# Lazy loading of image in ImageSpan

Tags: android, spannable

I want to build custom ImageSpan which set up default picture at the beginning of fetching data and loaded picture when fetching finished.

Example of code:

```
public class CustomImageSpan extends ImageSpan {

  private Drawable mDrawable;

   @Override
  public Drawable getDrawable() {
    if (mDrawable == null) {

      mDrawable = defaultDrawable;
      Futures.addCallback(
          FetchImage.submit(
              new FutureCallback<Image>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Image result) {
              Bitmap bitmap = result.getBitmap();
              mDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(mContext.getResources(), bitmap);

             //!Rerender span with new bitmap.
            }
          }, mExecutor);

     }

    return mDrawable;
  }
```

How to notify span that loading has finished and it`s time to get new bitmap instead of default??

Comment: You can get repeated images from cache, but it will not be possible to display the first image. I would recommend to rewrite the code which creates ImageSpans so that it creates them after the image is loaded.

Answer (score -1):

You could try and use a handler to proceed to the next task once the current one has completed

```
Handler xHandler=new Handler(){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message message){
            switch (message.what){
            case SOME_OPERATION:
                getImage(); //the method you are using
                break;
            }
        }
     };
```

run the handleer in a seprate thread as below

```
@Override
        public void run() {
            xHandler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(xHandler, SOME_OPERATION));
        }
```

Comment: Why are you down voting without explanation ? Kindly elaborate your rationale here